# Xamarin iOS Mac Build Host Port Number

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

What port number does the Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio and the Mac Build Host talk over? The Mac I am trying to connect to is not local, and I am looking to setup port forwarding. I just need to know the port number. I haven't been able to find it in any of the documentation.

This would be using all of the latest `stable` release components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/) should be port 5000.